# phpMyAdmin - SELECT statement's result in stored procedure not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I Have created a simple procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  `simpleProcedure` ( IN  `parameter` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM table1;    
END
```

Running this procedure using `CALL simpleProcedure(1)` in phpMyAdmin does not show the result of the query... How do I make phpMyAdmin show the result of the query inside the procedure?

Comment: what is your `phpmyadmin` version?

Comment: My `phpmyadmin` verion is `4.0.5`

Answer (score 0):

You need an **OUT** parameter for it to return results, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html.

Example from the sakila database:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `film_in_stock`(IN p_film_id INT, IN p_store_id INT, OUT p_film_count INT)
    READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN
     SELECT inventory_id
     FROM inventory
     WHERE film_id = p_film_id
     AND store_id = p_store_id
     AND inventory_in_stock(inventory_id);

     SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO p_film_count; 
END$$
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, it's possible to return the result of a `SELECT` query from a stored procedure so that running the procedure in phpMyAdmin results in displaying a table representing the result of the `SELECT` statement inside that procedure, how do I accomplish that?

Comment: I realize this is quite an old answer, but... You don't need any OUT parameter for a MySQL procedure to return a result set.  However, the issue is confused due to some versions of phpmyadmin sometimes not showing a result set under odd circumstances. Right now I'm dealing with an installation of phpmyadmin 4.8.4 in which no result set is shown unless there's at least one _input_ parameter, even just a dummy one that's not used. Define the procedure with one input parameter (no output parameters), and a simple SELECT statement, and it returns results just fine.